# Commit is grayed out in xcode9 source control

Tags: xcode, version-control, commit

I am taking a beginner's course online on iphone app development and am very new to using xcode/swift and programming in general.

I am trying to commit my code within xcode 9 but most of the options under the Source Control menu are grayed out, including the Commit option(see screenshot).

[image: commit grayed out]

Source control is enabled in the xcode settings (see screenshot)

[image: settings]

and I just updated to xcode Version 9.1 (9B55) and mac OS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G1036)but I'm still having the same problem.

I can't seem to figure out how to fix this and haven't been able to find the answer online. I was thinking I might delete xcode and reinstall it on my computer but I wanted to see if anyone here could help before I do that since I'm not sure if that will fix the problem anyway.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: Have you created or cloned a repository for this project?

Comment: No I have not. I don’t even know what that means, lol. and I was afraid to mess things up by trying. 

When the instructor did it, he simply selected “commit” so I didn’t know I had to do anything else.  I know I have a lot to learn...is that what you always have to do in order to commit?

Comment: No. Read 'Commit' as 'Commit the changes I have made to the repository', where 'Repository' is the place where your source control history is kept. At the moment you have no repository for this project so commit makes no sense. Once you have a repository you can change, commit, change, commit etc as you saw your instructor doing. Source control like this is _very_ useful, but not essential. Perhaps focus on the code for now and add source control to your toolkit later? Alternatively find a good resource on GIT to learn the basics.

Comment: thank you so much! that really helps me understand it better! you are very kind :0)